# Adding subclass object to superclass list

Tags: java, list

I have a method that takes a list of a super class (Specifically my class Mob). It looks like this:

```
List<? extends Mob> mobs
```

I want to be able to add any object which extends the super class Mob to this list, like this:

```
spawnMob(new Zombie(World.getInstance(), 0, 0), World.getInstance().getZombies());
```

Where this is the method in question:

```
public static void spawnMob(Mob mob, List<? extends Mob> mobs){
    mobs.add(mob);
}
```

This line of code `World.getInstance().getZombies()` returns a List of the object Zombie. Zombie extends Mob.

However, this line of code:

```
mobs.add(mob);
```

Throws this error:

```
The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Mob) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Mob> is not applicable for the arguments (Mob)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Edit, after changing the method to except `List<Mob>` I receive this error:

```
The method spawnMob(Mob, List<Mob>) in the type MobSpawner is not applicable for the arguments (Zombie, List<Zombie>)
```

Comment: Why don't define your list as `List<Mob> mobs`? You can still add objects extending Mob to that list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add anything but `null` to a `List` specified with an upper bounded wildcard.  A `List<? extends Mob>` could be of anything that extends `Mob`.  It could be a `List<Mafia>` for all the compiler knows.  You shouldn't be able to add a `Zombie` to a `List` that could be a `List<Mafia>`.  To preserve type safety, the compiler must prevent such calls.

To add to such a list, you must remove the wildcard.

```
public static void spawnMob(Mob mob, List<Mob> mobs){
```

If you might have to pass in `List`s with specific subclasses, then consider making the method generic:

```
public static <T extends Mob> void spawnMob(T mob, List<T> mobs){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `List<Mob> mobs`.

Comment: This makes sense, but I receive this error now `The method spawnMob(Mob, List<Mob>) in the type MobSpawner is not applicable for the arguments (Zombie, List<Zombie>)`

Comment: Don't change the method, just change the ``mobs`` declaration

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare the list as `List<Mob> mobs`, and any subclass of `Mob` will be accepted. Note that when you get items from the list, you will only know for certain that they are of type `Mob`. You will have to do some testing to see what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just create mobs list as

```
List<Mob> mobs;
```